# is there a way to change the time for autodelete Mysite in SharePoint

Tags: mysite

Im looking at editing changing the time for the autodelete mysite from 14 days to 30 days.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question to a developer that set up the standard clean up job for us a while ago.

He said no, since it was ingrained in the system, and you cannot also change the text of the email that is sent to the 'report to' person for the same reason.